# Given a root, determine $a$ and $b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

> Given $p(x)= x^3 + ax^2 + bx -6$ with a zero at $x=1+i$. Determine the values of $a$ and $b$.

With the question given in its current form, would it be reasonable to assume that both $a$ and $b$ are real? Since, if so, one may use the fact that $x= 1-i$ is also a zero, and therefore find a quadratic factor and use that to proceed.

Or is there another way to proceed to answer this question without having to assume real coefficients?

Comment: are $a,b$ supposed to real numbers?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner . That is exactly what I am trying to figure out. I was given this question by a high school student and feel that it might be slightly incomplete in its given form. As in order to use the fact that we know the second root, we require the coefficients to be real (which the question does not state). So I want to figure out if it is necessary to assume that, or if there is another way to proceed answering this question without having to assume they are real.

Comment: What is $p(x)$? Is that a *polynomial* function of $x$?

Comment: @user477343: $x^3+ax^2+bx-6$ certainly looks polynomial to me.

Comment: @celtschk I know, but I have never seen the notation $p(x)$ before.

Comment: @user477343  . It is a polynomial indeed :)

Comment: @user477343: I struggle to understand where your problem is. You don't know the notation $f(x)$ for a function named $f$ depending on the variable $x$? Or is your problem that this specific function happens not to be called $f$ or $g$, but $p$?

Comment: @celtschk it was that I knew that $p$ was a function. I just was curious to know why $p$ was chosen as opposed to $f$ or something like that. I have seen $f$ and $g$ and $f\circ g$ and things like that.

Comment: @user477343: While only the author of the text can give an authoritative answer as to why that letter was chosen, it almost certainly was chosen because it is a polynomial function. Just as for an arbitrary function, $f$ is usually chosen just because "function" starts with "f", and if you need a second function, $g$ is usually chosen because "g" just happens to be the next letter after "f".

Comment: @celtschk yes, yes I know that haha. In fact, I didn’t need explanation for that since it is quite trivial as to why we would have a function $g$ after $f$, like how $a^2 + b^2$ most of the time equals $c^2$. Sometimes people use $h^2$, but even that is understandable (i.e. $h$ for *hypotenuse*). I just wanted to be absolutely certain is all. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $p(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx - 6$. We are told that $p(1 + i) = 0$. Then,
$$\begin{align}
(1 + i)^3 + a(1 + i)^2 + b(1 + i) - 6 &= 0\\
(-2 + 2i) + 2ai + b(1 + i) - 6 &= 0\\
(b - 8) + (2a + b + 2)i &= 0
\end{align}$$
Hence, the real and imaginary parts need to be equal to $0$. This gives us $b = 8$, and consequently, $a = -5$.

EDIT: I just realized that this assumes that $a$ and $b$ are real... So if you decide that the question requires that (reasonable IMO), then this is the solution.

EDIT 2: With celtschk's comment, I decided to take this a bit further. Let's allow the possibility for $a,b$ to be complex. Suppose that $a = x + iy$ and $b = u + iv$ where $x,y,u,v \in \mathbb{R}$. Then,
$$\begin{align}
((u + iv) - 8) + (2(x + iy) + (u + iv) + 2)i &= 0\\
(u - 2y - v - 8) + (2x + u + v + 2)i &= 0
\end{align}$$
Since all the variables in the above equation are real, we can (without loss of generality) conclude that
$$\begin{align}
u - 2y - 2v - 8 &= 0\\
2x + u + v + 2&= 0
\end{align}$$

So the above equations describe the complete set of solutions to $a = x + iy$ and $b = u + iv$. Notice that if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then $y = v = 0$ and the solution simplifies to $b = u = 8$ and $a = x = -5$.

Comment: Thank you! It seems the only way to proceed then, is to assume both $a$ and $b$ are real. Thanks for confirming my suspicion and for providing a nicely laid out solution

Comment: The question is exactly whether that may be assumed. Note however that the last displayed equation is still independent of that; it gives a dependence between $a$ and $b$. It can be simplified to $2ai + b(1+i) = 8-2i$. Which describes the complete set of solutions if no reality assumption is made. BTW, I'm not sure if it is a reasonable assumption; I see nothing in the question that suggests that there has to be exactly one solution.

Comment: BTW, if  were given this as homework, I'd probably play safe: First state the general set of solutions without restriction to reals, and then state that the only real solution in that set is $a=-5$ and $b=8$. If the question was meant without restriction, the last point just gives additional information after the explicitly states solution before. If the question was meant with restriction, the solution is in the last sentence, and the general solution before was just a step in its derivation.

Comment: @celtschk Good points. I updated my answer to include the more general case. Seeing as how the general case is a solution with $3$ parameters, I think it's safe to conclude that $a,b$ should be real.

Comment: This site never seizes to amaze me. Thank you all for the wonderful responses. The high school student is taking an advanced program mathematics course (college level), and so I feel she is on the level to understand both solutions. :). I will use this as guideline to explain to her.

Comment: No problem @DJS! I think we all get satisfaction from helping others understand this wonderful subject :)

Comment: The set of solution has exactly one complex, or 2 real parameters. The set of solutions can be given as $a = \frac{i-1}{2}b -1-4i$ with $b\in\mathbb C$ arbitrary. There's no reason to separate the complex number in real and imaginary part.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I had $4$ unknowns and $2$ equations so that $2$ can be chosen as parameters, yet I somehow messed that one up and said $3$.. Additionally, I felt that there was some instructional value to separating into real and imaginary parts, but your representation is definitely the "better" one.

Answer (score 2):

Which says that $x^3+ax^2+bx-6$ is divisible by $$(x-1+i)(x-1-i)=(x-1)^2-i^2=x^2-2x+2$$ and since
$$x^3+ax^2+bx-6=x^3-2x^2+2x+(a+2)x^2+(b-2)x-6,$$ we obtain $a+2=-3$ and $b-2=6$,

which gives $$(a,b)=(-5,8).$$

Answer (score 1):

The other answers give the solution for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and, since the problem was posed at a high school, I suppose that this is the case.

If we can have $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ than the problem has infinitely many solutions.  In this case also the other two solutions can be complex numbers $u$ and $v$ not related to the given $z=1+i$ and , using [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we can write the system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
-a=u+v+z\\
b=uv+uz+vz\\
6=uvz
\end{cases}
$$
from which, given $z$, we can find $a$ and $b$ as functions of one of the other roots.